# Javascript as a bookmark (Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarks

I saw that it was possible to put Javascript code as a bookmark 'URL' on Google Chrome.
I would like to use this to fill a form with the previous page's URL.

For example, if I focus on a Youtube page, and then clic on that bookmark, I want it to fill this page's form with the previous Youtube URL : http://www.proxfree.com/youtube-proxy.php

This is what I tried but it keeps failing, it only loads the new page but doesn't do anything with the form :

```
javascript: var yturl = document.URL; 
document.location = 'http://www.proxfree.com/youtube-proxy.php';
document.getElementsByName('get').value(yturl);
```

I thought it failed because the page needed to be fully loaded before searching for the input named 'get' in the form.
But I can't redefine the onload function as the proxfree.com page already defines it. Besides I can't use jQuery's loaded function in a bookmark's code.

Do you have any clue how I could auto-fill this form ?

Comment: It's all about security. Could be used for XSS. So short: this wont work. Look at the URL proxfree gives you. If you can append the URL just do: `document.location = 'http://www.proxfree.com/youtube-proxy.php'+document.URL;`

Comment: Oh ok. I checked for URL modification but unfortunately the form goes to a PHP page using POST, which redirects me to a randomly generated URL.

Comment: @Stephan It is not really security as much as the fact you can not run code like that. If you were on the same domain, it still would not work.

Comment: @epascarello What do you mean ?

Comment: *What do you mean ?*  You can not change the location of the page and execute code on the next page. It is impossible to do that.